# How do I add Firestore to my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Javascript, I've been trying to add Firestore using the code below:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-analytics.js";
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-firestore.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXX"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db =  getFirestore();   

db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", "1234")
.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        console.log("change ", change.doc.data());
    });
});
```

However, I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: db.collection is not a function

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using modular version so try refactoring the onSnapshot to this syntax:

```
import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-firestore.js";

const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", "1234"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  const documents = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      documents.push(doc.data().name);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Google need to improve their documentation!

Comment: @jennie788 it's in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection). Make sure you are on `Modular Tab`.

Comment: Hey @jennie788 If my answer was useful you can accept ✔ it so others will know this is resolved.